# Вопрос по Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

```
tmp = [set()] * 3
tmp[1].add(2)
print(tmp)
```

Вопрос такой: почему в выше написанном коде Питон добавляет `2` во все множества из списка `tmp`, а не только в указанное множество с индексом `tmp[1]`.

Comment: Потому что вы не создали три разных множества, а использовали **одно и то же множество** три раза. Если вам нужно создать именно три разных множества, используйте что-то вроде `tmp = [set() for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Просто я думал, что даже если изначально множества в списке одинаковые, то все равно они отличаются по индексу. Поэтому рассчитывал на то, что написав "tmp[1]" я беру в работу конкретный элемент списка и изменяю только его

Comment: Написав tmp[1], вы получаете объект из конкретного элемента списка, но в других элементах списка лежит тот же самый объект

Comment: Я понял о чем Вы, спасибо большое!